# mknod operation not permitted

Tags: linux, unix, mknod

i have problem with this makefile always tell me mknod 'T0' operation not permitted

```
all: tx es_mux demux
     mknod T0 p
     mknod T1 p
     mknod T2 p
     mknod T3 p
     mknod T4 p
     mknod T5 p
     mknod T6 p
     mknod T7 p
     mknod T8 p
     mknod T9 p

tx: 
    gcc -Wall tx.c -o tx

es_mux: 
    gcc -Wall es_mux.c  -o es_mux

demux:
    gcc -Wall demux.c  -o demux

clean: 
    rm -f tx
    rm -f demux
    rm -f es_mux
    rm -f T0 T1 T2 T3 T4 T5 T6 T7 T8 T9
```

I'm running a virtual machine with parallels on a MBP.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have permissions to do this on the current working directory? mknod is usually meant to create named pipes nowadays.  IT can also create character special files or file found in the /dev directory.  Why the heck do you need those pipes - if that is what they are supposed to be?
I cannot see why those are needed in your makefile. gcc does not require them.

(consider mkfifo for pipes, anyway):